# NameError: name 'yearout' is not defined

Tags: python

Please tell me what is wrong, and other ways it needs improving

```
def finalcalc(y, d, m):
    end = (y + d + m) % 7
    return end
def monthlook(m):
    if m == 1:
        monthout = 6
    elif m == 2:
        monthout = 2
    elif m == 3:
        monthout = 2
    elif m == 4:
        monthout = 5
    elif m == 5:
        monthout = 0
    elif m == 6:
        monthout = 3
    elif m == 7:
        monthout = 5
    elif m == 8:
        monthout = 1
    elif m == 9:
        monthout = 4
    elif m == 10:
        monthout = 6
    elif m == 11:
        monthout = 2
    elif m == 12:
        monthout = 4
print(finalcalc(yearout, dayout, monthout))    
def daysimp(d):
    dayout = d % 7
    monthlook(monthin)
def yearc(y):
    y = y % 100
    yearout = y + (y // 4)
    yearrem = y % 4
    if yearrem >= 2:
        yearout += 1
    yearout = yearout % 7
    daysimp(dayin)
dayin = int(input("What day in the Month?"))
monthin = int(input("What Month Number? - Eg. January is 1"))
yearin = int(input("What Year?"))
yearc(yearin)
```

The Error Says: "NameError: name 'yearout' is not defined"- Please give me solution and answers to any other problems you find, and ways it could be simplified and/or improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yearout` is a name defined in the function `yearc` *only*; when you call `finalcalc()` the name is not visible and you get your error.

You have the same problem with `dayout` and `monthout`.

You need to decide what the values for `yearout`, `dayout` and `monthout` should *be* before you call `finalcalc()`. Perhaps you wanted to set those names to the result of other functions? Those functions then need to use `return` to make those values available to the caller.

For example, change the `yearc` function to return the new `yearout` value:

```
def yearc(y):
    y = y % 100
    yearout = y + (y // 4)
    yearrem = y % 4
    if yearrem >= 2:
        yearout += 1
    yearout = yearout % 7
    return yearout
```

then store the result of that function in a new name:

```
yearout = yearc(yearin)
```

and do the same for the other names and functions.

You really want to read through the [Python tutorial on functions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) again.

Comment: What do I change? Like I said I am new to Python.

Comment: @user2080262: There is a lot wrong here; perhaps you need to go over your tutorial a little more carefully again?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than calling your methods sequentially from other methods, you should rather return the value from each method, and then invoke the next method to get next value.

Since, it seems like you want to pass the values calculated in those three methods to your `finalcalc` method, you need to change your methods to return those values - `yearout`, `dayout`, and `monthout`, and store the return value in some variable. And then you can use those return values as arguments to `finalcalc` method:

```
yearout = yearc(yearin)
monthout = monthlook(monthin)
daysout = daysimp(dayin)

print(finalcalc(yearout, dayout, monthout))
```

And your method `daysimp` can be simply changed to:

```
def daysimp(d):
    return d % 7
```

Similarly modify other 2 methods.